# Assert that viewController is both delegate and dataSource of its tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, assert

As a sanity check, I would like to assert in `viewDidLoad` that a `UITableViewController` (i.e. `self`) is set both as `dataSource` and `delegate` of its `tableView`. How can I put this in Swift 3, where (unlike with Objective-C) additional type casts are needed? This still leads to syntax errors:

```
assert(tableView.dataSource == self)
assert(tableView.delegate   == self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the object instance equality operator '===':

```
assert(tableView.dataSource === self)
assert(tableView.delegate === self)
```

Comment: Thx. Rookie mistake!